# ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, ado.net, c#-5.0

This seems silly but I can't put my finger on this. What am I doing wrong here? It's a common error but I don't seem to be making the same mistakes as on the other couple of dozens of posts on here...

```
    public static string Insert(SqlCommand cmd, SqlConnection connection) 
    {
        //feedback to user on whether the insert was successful
        string success = "Success! Thank you for contributing to this project";

        int added = 0;

        //connect and insert the data
        try
        {
            using (connection)
            {
                connection.Open();
                added = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                //update success variable
                success += "\n" + added.ToString() + " records inserted.";
            }//end using(connection)
        }//end try

        catch (Exception err)
        {
            //if we have an error, return this message for debugging purposes for now
            string message = err.Message;
            return message;
        }//end catch

        return success;
    }//end Insert()
```

Comment: Where do you get the error ?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? What's returned after running that function?

Comment: Right! I wasn't entirely clear. I get the error in the title right after the statement `code` added = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); `code` is run. Then it jumps straight to the error-handling code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Command` object probably does not have the connection, as you are passing both `Connection` and `Command` to your method. You need to assign the connection to command object property `Connection`.

```
try
{
    using (connection)
    {
        cmd.Connection = connection; //Here assign connection to command object
        connection.Open();
        added = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //update success variable
        success += "\n" + added.ToString() + " records inserted.";
    }//end using(connection)
}//end try
```

Comment: That very much was my issue. (and by the way, this was my virgin post on StackOverFlow, so thanks for making me feel welcome :)

Comment: You are welcome @JacquesPluviose, welcome to SO, its good to see your first post with your effort and formatting.